# How do i use try catch in multiple sets of arrays in jq?

Tags: jq

json example:

```
{
  "data": {
    "sub1": [
      {
        "sub2": {
          "sub3": 32,
          "steps": []
        }
      },
      {
        "sub2": {
          "sub3": 21,
          "steps": [
            {
              "task": [
                {
                  "active": 223,
                  "activel": 21
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "sub2": {
          "sub3": 234,
          "steps": [
            {
              "task": [
                {
                  "active": 23,
                  "activel": 2
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "sub2": {
          "sub3": 32,
          "steps": [
            {
              "task": []
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

what i have tried:

```
.data.sub1[]| [try(.sub2.steps[].task[].active) catch "error"]
```

in jqplay : https://jqplay.org/s/U2mWmdkhsm5

this is the closest i have gotten, but what i need is for it to write error for each part of the array where active doesnt exist.
like this:

```
"error"
223
23
"error"
```

this seems like a simple question, but i just cant figure out how to get this to work, so thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [alternative operator `//`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://):

```
.data.sub1[] | .sub2.steps[].task[].active // "error"
```

See [playground](https://jqplay.org/s/1GQqTF1X2At).